# How can scalar mesons have even parity?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, parity, mesons

From my understanding a pseudo-scalar meson has:

$$J^P=0^-$$

That makes sense since the total spin $S=0$ and $l$ must be $l=0$ which makes the parity:

$$ P=(-1)^{l+1}=-1 $$

uneven. Now, for scalar mesons the parity is even. If $S=0$, then to make the parity even $l=1$, but that violates the fact $J=l+S=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalar mesons, $0^+$ (as well as tensors, $2^+$), can be easily formed by
$S=1=l$, so adding them can yield $J=0$ or 2, with *P=+*.

Bonus: $C=(-)^{S+l}$ so ,e.g., the $f_0$  has *C* =+ and hence can decay to γγ.

Comment: Of course! I forgot when adding the vectors $S$ and $l$, $J$ kan take values of $|l-S| \leq J \leq J+S$. Thanks!